# Search index and SSA only for Task list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, searchserviceapplication

I have a web application with n number of site collections and each site collection has a custom Task list and other list. 
Is it possible to create a search topology to index only the custom Task list and create a Content Search Web Part connected to this index?

Answer (score 0):

A separate SSA would be overkill (IMHO). If I were you I'd create a Result Source for that list and then bind the search result to the Result Source.

Comment: We already have a result source only for the Task list and is connected to the Content search Webpart but the Problem is with the crawler. Even with Continuous crawl its taking 15 min for the result to appear in the Content search Webpart.

Comment: Then is is working as designed. It should take no more than 15 minutes and sometimes less. Continuous is triggered by a timer job.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, You can use the Content Search web part and 
"contentclass:STS_List_Task" query to get all the Task lists. You can follow below steps:

1. Edit the page that you want to display content and select add a web part. Choose and add a Content Search Web Part.
2. Edit the web part, click “change query” button and specify you query.
3. Switch to advanced mode, in “query text” region, enter the following text:

   contentclass:STS_List_Task

"contentclass:STS_List_Task" is used to filter by task lists only.

For more information about SP search using contentclass:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/02/16/sharepoint-power-searching-using-contentclass/